# Initialize a constant pointer to a constant object in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Is it possible to create a constant pointer to a constant float?
I'm doing this but in this case temp is not constant.

```
float* temp = malloc(sizeof(float));
*temp = 22.5;
const float *const border = temp;
```

I'm well aware that this scenario won't be practicable in any real life situations.

Comment: First of all, pick *one* language, the one you're actually programming in. Secondly, why do you allocate memory for a single `float` value with `malloc`?

Comment: How much more constantness of `temp` would you want? What have you tried? Why use `temp` at all if you assign it to `border` lateron?

Comment: Which parts are from different languages? I have the task for learning purposes to only use the stack for pointers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I want a constant pointer to a constant float laying on the heap

Comment: What is `border` to you? To me, it fits that description.

Comment: what's the point? you could create it in a function.

Comment: Hint: The purpose of the heap is contrary to the concept of `const` objects. A second note: C does not support constants other than what's called literals in other languages. `const` qualified objects are still variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly 
`float* temp = malloc(sizeof(float));` 
should be

`float* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); /* it works for any data type */`

Secondly,*Is it possible to create a constant pointer to a constant float?* yes its possible.

```
int main() {

        float *temp = (const float*)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        *temp = 22.5;
        const float *const border = temp; /* value & address both constant */

        /* now you can modify border and temp */
        #if 0
        *border = 10.5; /* not possible, cant change value*/
        border+=1;/* not possible, can't change address */
        #endif

        /* once done , free() it */
        free(temp);
        return 0;
}
```

But in above example `*temp = 10.5` is possible because `*temp` is not `constant`.

Comment: This will generate multiple diagnostics and is very wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf but may I know the diagnostics ?

Comment: Use a modern compiler and see for yourself. You could, of course also try to deduce it from the code you show. It should be obvious.

Comment: I tried with enabling flags and all other stuff, I didn't get anything. That's why I am asking ?

Comment: @Olaf achal means that the offending code is disabled by `#if 0`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Sorry, I was in wekend-mode. The definition&initialisation of `border` is ok. That whole thing is just very bad practice (as is what OP _might_ have in mind).

Comment: Although the concept of my question might be very wrong it is what i wanted. Thanks for that! I also get the compiler warning for that.